# How to add a string to every line in a file with Bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

I have a file (`myfile.txt`) that contains these lines:

```
foo
bar
qux
```

In a bash script I'd like to add a value on the string
resulting in

```
foo 1000
bar 1000
qux 1000
```

I tried this but failed.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
MYVAL="1000"
cat myfile.txt | xargs -I '{}' echo {} & echo $MYVAL
```

which only prints 1000 on one line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sed` and you don't really need a pipe for this:

```
myval="1000"
sed "s/$/ $myval/" file > file.modified
```

for in-place editing:

```
sed -i "s/$/ $myval/" file
```

- `s/$/ $myval/` - places a space followed by the value of `$myval` at the end of each line

---

More about `sed` here: http://grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is almost there:

```
$ xargs -I{} echo {} 1000 < file6
boo djhg 1000
bio jdjjf 1000
dgdhd bgo 1000
ghhh 1000
baao biologico bata 1000
baa beto biologic 1000
bojo bija 1000
```